# Localhost cannot connect to ASP file in IIS

Tags: javascript, html, iis, webforms, localhost

[EDIT: Solution found.  I had simply not set up or attempted to access the localhost correctly, which meant the files were not being loaded.  Once I tried accessing the files through a localhost instead of the absolute path, I found they worked.  I'm leaving the question up in the rare event that it helps someone in the future.]

I am trying to complete a web form exercise before I begin classes in September.  The goal is simple: make an HTML file that takes some user input, and send it to an ASP file (not ASP.NET) hosted locally to confirm the data was actually sent.  There isn't any need to parse the data, just to recognize that it was successfully sent with GET or POST.

I have made the HTML file, and the ASP file has been provided as part of the exercise.  I have checked both of them thoroughly, and the  element is sending data properly, but the ASP file does not seem to be receiving it properly.

I have done the following steps to configure an ASP file using IIS on my laptop, which is running Windows 10:

- Install IIS and support for classic ASP files
- Ensure the default port (80) is open and listening
- Ensure the website is running in IIS

However, when I try to browse the website using localhost/fileName.asp as a URL, it does not load properly.  I instead receive the error "localhost refused to connect."  When I try browsing the site using the "browse" button in the IIS manager interface, I receive the error message  "Localhost application not found."

Weirdly, when I open the HTML page in a browser and click the submit button, it redirects me to the .ASP page, but does not execute any of the contents of it.  It just displays the text contents of the file.

For reference, I have provided the code of my HTML page and the ASP page below.  I have removed the input elements from the HTML page because they are not relevant to my problem.

HTML:

```
<html>

    <head>
        <title>SET Registration</title>

    </head>

    <body>

        <div name="errorMessage" id="D3" style="color:red"></div>

        <form action="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\testRequest.asp" method="get">

            <!--INPUT ELEMENTS THAT GET INFORMATION FROM USER-->

            <!--BUTTONS THAT CLEAR/VALIDATE/SUBMIT FORM INFORMATION-->
            <input type="button" name="cancelForm" id="B1" value="Clear all" onclick=clearAll()>

            <input type="button" name="validateForm" id="B3" value="Validate data" onclick=validateForm()>

            <input type="submit" name="submitForm" id="B2" value="Submit form">

        </form>

        <script type="application/javascript">
            //shows the student checklist div and hides the faculty one
            function showStudentDiv() {
                document.getElementById("D2").hidden = true;
                document.getElementById("D1").hidden = false;
            }

            //shows the faculty checklist div and hides the student one
            function showFacultyDiv() {
                document.getElementById("D1").hidden = true;
                document.getElementById("D2").hidden = false;
            }

            //checks if a character is a letter or not
            function isLetter(str) {
                if (str.length == 1 && str.match(/[a-z]/i)) {
                    return true;
                } else return false;
            }

            //clears all fields, but does not reset values because values are only updated when trying to be validated
            function clearAll() {
                //clear the error message field
                document.getElementById("D3").innerHTML = "";

                //reset each text field to default values
                document.getElementById("F1").value = "";
                document.getElementById("F2").value = "";
                document.getElementById("F3").value = "";
                document.getElementById("F4").value = "";
                document.getElementById("F5").value = "";

                //uncheck the radio buttons and hide the divs they control
                document.getElementById("F6").checked = false;
                document.getElementById("F7").checked = false;
                document.getElementById("D1").hidden = true;
                document.getElementById("D2").hidden = true;

                //uncheck every checkbox in the divs controlled by radio buttons
                document.getElementById("F8").checked = false;
                document.getElementById("F9").checked = false;
                document.getElementById("F10").checked = false;
                document.getElementById("F11").checked = false;
                document.getElementById("F12").checked = false;
                document.getElementById("F13").checked = false;
                document.getElementById("F14").checked = false;
            }

            //test function to see if the "Validate data" button has scope to this area of code
            function validateForm() {
                alert("function was called 2");
            }

            //validates each field in the page and returns true ONLY if every single field is valid
            function submitForm() {
                alert("function was called");
                //validate fields, then submit form
                    //postal code must be of proper form
                    //at least one radio button must have "checked == true"
                    //all text fields must have data in them
                var formIsValid = true;
                //var whichProblem = "";

                //check to ensure the first five fields are not empty
                if (document.getElementById("F1").value == "") {
                    formisValid = false;
                    errorMessage("F1");
                } else if (document.getElementById("F2").value == "") {
                    formisValid = false;
                    errorMessage("F2");
                } else if (document.getElementById("F3").value == "") {
                    formisValid = false;
                    errorMessage("F3");
                } else if (document.getElementById("F4").value == "") {
                    formisValid = false;
                    errorMessage("F4");
                } else if (document.getElementById("F5").value.length != 6) {
                    formisValid = false;
                    errorMessage("F5");
                }

                if (isValidPostalCode(document.getElementById("F5")) == false) {
                    formIsValid = false;
                }

                if (document.getElementById("F6").checked == false && document.getElementById("F7") == false) {
                    formIsValid = false;
                }

                if (formIsValid == true) {

                }

            }

            //validates a 6-character string as a Canadian postal code: returns false if any character is invalid
                //Note: the "doument.write" line at the bottom is a placeholder for testing - in the real assignment, this
                //function would simply return true
            function isValidPostalCode(postalCode) {
                var PC1 = false;
                var PC2 = false;
                var PC3 = false;
                var PC4 = false;
                var PC5 = false;
                var PC6 = false;
                //check to ensure the postal code is of the proper form
                //define a list of valid characters for each place in the postal code
                var postalChar1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'E', 'G', 'J', 'H', 'K', 'M', 'N', 'L', 'P', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'X', 'V', 'Y'];
                var postalChar246 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

                //check 1st character
                for (var i = 0; i < postalChar1.length; i++) {
                    if (postalCode[0] == postalChar1[i]) {
                        PC1 = true;
                    }
                }

                //check characters 2, 4, and 6 to see if they are numbers 0-9
                for (var i = 0; i < postalChar246.length; i++) {
                    if (Number(postalCode[1]) == postalChar246[i]) {
                        PC2 = true;
                    }
                }
                for (var i = 0; i < postalChar246.length; i++) {
                    if (Number(postalCode[3]) == postalChar246[i]) {
                        PC4 = true;
                    }
                }
                for (var i = 0; i < postalChar246.length; i++) {
                    if (Number(postalCode[5]) == postalChar246[i]) {
                        PC6 = true;
                    }
                }

                //check characters 3 and 5 to see if they are letters
                if (isLetter(postalCode[2]) == true) {
                    PC3 = true;
                }
                if (isLetter(postalCode[4]) == true) {
                    PC5 = true;
                }

                //1st is specific letters
                //2nd is any number 0-9
                //3rd is any letter
                //4th is any number 0-9
                //5th is any letter
                //6th is any number 0-9

                if (PC1 == false || PC2 == false || PC3 == false || PC4 == false || PC5 == false || PC6 == false) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    document.write("Form submission successful");
                }
            }

            //displays an error message to the user if he entered invalid data, depending on the field
            function errorMessage(messageCode) {
                if (messageCode == "F1") {
                    alert("You must enter a name.");
                } else if (messageCode == "F2") {
                    alert("You must enter a street.");
                } else if (messageCode == "F3") {
                    alert("You must enter a city.");
                } else if (messageCode == "F4") {
                    alert("You must choose a province or territory.");
                } else if (messageCode == "F5") {
                    alert("You must enter a valid Canadian Postal code (A#A #A#).");
                } else if (messageCode == "F6" || messageCode == "F7") {
                    alert("You must indicate if you are a student or faculty.");
                } 
            }

        </script>

    </body>




</html>
```

ASP:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>WDD : A-02</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .style1 { text-align: center; font-family: Calibri, Arial, sans-serif; }
        .style2 { font-family: Calibri, Arial, sans-serif; }
        td { font-family: Consolas, sans-serif; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="style1"> WDD (PROG2000) : A-02 : The <i>Form Listener</i></h1>
    <br />
    <h3 class="style2"> Response page for either a GET or POST method.</h3>
<br />
<%
dim i

i=1
if request.querystring<>"" then
    response.write "<p class='style2'>You sent data to <i>testRequest.asp</i> using the <b>GET</b> action ... Here is what you sent:<br/><br/></p><div align='center'><table border='0'>"
    for each str in request.querystring
        response.write "<tr><td width='120' align='right'>Parameter "&CStr(i)&":</td><td width='150' align='right'>"& str & "</td><td width='40' align='center'>=</td><td width='250' align='left'>" & request.querystring(str).Item & "</td></tr>"
       i=i+1
    next
    response.write "</table></div>"
else
    if request.form <>"" then
        response.write "<p class='style2'>You sent data to <i>testRequest.asp</i> using the <b>POST</b> action ... Here is what you sent:<br/><br/></p><div align='center'><table border='0'>"
        for each str in request.form
            response.write "<tr><td width='120' align='right'>Parameter "&CStr(i)&":</td><td width='150' align='right'>"& str & "</td><td width='40' align='center'>=</td><td width='250' align='left'>" & request.form(str).Item & "</td></tr>"
         i=i+1
        next
        response.write "</table></div>"
    else
        response.write "<p class='style2'>Hey ... There is no GET or POST method in use!</p>"
    end if
end if
%>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I think this issue is not related with your classic aspo codes.

I suggest you could try to run below command to check the iplisten.

Run below cmd command:

```
netsh http show iplisten
```

if you receive the output of above command somethign other than 0.0.0.0, you could try to run below command to delete the other iplisten

```
netsh http delete iplisten ipaddress=aa.bb.cc.dd (where aa.bb.cc.dd is the IP address that we have to remmove)

netsh http add iplisten ipaddress=0.0.0.0

iisreset
```

If this solution doesn't solve your issue, I suggest you could refer to below article to clean reinstall IIS.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/friis/2017/01/16/how-to-perform-a-clean-reinstallation-of-iis/

Comment: I figured out a solution myself, actually, and you were right in that it had nothing to do with the actual code.  The problem was that I hadn't properly configured the localhost to "look at" the files, so it couldn't render a proper webpage.

Pretty silly in retrospect, but I appreciate you taking the time to try helping me anyway.